# Filter datagridview using two textboxes and datetimepicker in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datagrid

In my winforms application I have large datagridview link to mysql database. I want to filter my datagrid view using these three database column values

```
" username "
" loannumber "
" date "      ( i stored date in database using datetimepicker.text value )
```

And I implemented following code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataView DV = new DataView(dbdataset);
        DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert([loannumber], System.String) LIKE '%{0}%' OR   [username] LIKE '%{0}%'",loannumberseach.Text, procename.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In this code I added two search methods, but when I tried to filter with `username` AND `loannumber` it's not working.

Anyway I am not add the date time picker text because the above code is not working.

I want to achieve this.

I want to filter my datagrid view using `date` OR `loannumber` OR `username` using one button. If the the user only enters the only `loannumber`, datagrid should filter with `loannumber` without other two fields.

Is it possible to do this using only one button? Can someone please show me how to do this?

Comment: Thanks to edit and fix my question problems, but i have no idea why are you marked my non code part as a code :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change username LIKE '%[1]%' you put 0

Comment: sorry i mistakenly put the wrong code. however putting 1 instead of  0 not fixed the problem :(

Comment: I want to filter using both 3 of them

Comment: What you mean by unwanted string ? I'm sorry i'm new to programming could you please specify what unwanted space should i remove ?

Comment: try this Convert(loannumber, System.String) LIKE '%{0}%' OR username LIKE '%{1}%'

Comment: No it filter the data but not using both inputs.i want to filter my datagridview suing "username" "loannumber" and "date" values. exactly i want to find how many loans user processed in selected date. but if we only enter the one value datagrid should filter with it. as a example if i pick the date 2014-9-9 in date time picker, datagrid should show all the loan numbers that processed today, and if i only enter the loan number, it should filter with loan number, and i enter the username it should filter all the loan number that user processed the selected date

Comment: I have implement same example in my own test project I have done following in rowfilter it works for me String.Format("name LIKE '%{0}%' OR Convert(ID,System.String) LIKE '%{1}%'","xyz",1);  Its the same you are trying . I would suggest try to run same command in sql server and check the results

Comment: Yes but in this method i need to fill both search values. but when i provide only one value (eg. "loannumber") it shows nothing :(

Comment: ok. you can write this with if condition and change dv.RowFilter according to it. If you want to search with loan number then filter will be string.Format("Convert([loannumber], System.String) LIKE '%{0}%',loannumberseach.Text) if you want to search with date and loan put two conditions with OR . It may help

Comment: thanks :) it worked. I re-write the connection string and mysql command now it's working flawlessly